# User's document directory returning nil with FileManager

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, file, null

I'm trying to write a file locally but no success. When I try to get the user's document directory it returns nil and I believe this is why my file is not been stored.

Also, I have many doubts of what the "user's document directory" is supposed to mean. Is it the "Documents/" inside "iCloud Drive" or "on my phone". Should I be looking in another place instead of "Files" app? I'm using the iPhone simulator.

My code is designed as follow. *documentFolderURL*, *fileURL* and *url* are all nil when debugging.

```
let documentFolderURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last
        let ext: String = type ?? "pdf"
        let name = "extrato." + ext
        let fileURL = documentFolderURL?.appendingPathComponent(name)
        do {
            if let url = fileURL {
                try file.write(to: url, options: .atomic)
            }
        } catch {...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are creating the file successfully, but you aren't looking for it in the right place.

You can navigate to the simulator's **User Defaults** folder by:

1. Print the file path of the simulator's documents directory. `print(documentFolderURL)` should print something like **file:///Users/yourname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8DAF542C-4B37-41D1-BA43-1D7C2A32E585/data/Containers/Data/Application/63545C94-56F5-3B11-B601-543801BE717A/Documents/**
2. Copy the entire url **EXCEPT** the leading **file://** (in other words, start with **/User/yourname**...
3. Open your macbook's Finder app, and press **command** + **shift** + **g**. This will allow you to...(drum roll please)...
4. Paste in the url to navigate to your simulator's documents directory.

Your file should be there :)

Comment: You were right, my file was there :) I was looking only inside the simulator.
I just don't get why documentFolderURL is nil when debugging but give me some value when printed. Anyway, thank you very much!

Comment: I'm really not that familiar with debugging (since I'm kind of new too) so unfortunately I wouldn't know. But glad you found the file! P.S., if you thought my answer was correct, could you accept it as the correct solution? Since I am new to stack overflow, that would help boost my reputation  Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `throw`ing API to get an error (there should be none)

```
do {
    let documentFolderURL = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    let ext: String = type ?? "pdf"
    let fileURL = documentFolderURL.appendingPathComponent(name).appendingPathExtension(ext)
    try file.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)       
} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: Then the file has been written successfully.